# Cakephp htaccess mod_rewrite on GoDaddy

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have a godaddy hosting account and having some problems with
routing. The files are under **/cakephp** under the default **/html** folder.
The full url is still showing instead of the desired

```
 www[dot]domain[dot]org
```

Please help.

The current setup

/cakephp/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cakephp
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/cakephp/app/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cakephp
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/cakephp/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cakephp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can access your application from:

```
# http://example.com/cakephp/*   # normally served from html/cakephp/
```

... but instead you want URLs to display like this:

```
# http://example.com/*           # normally served from html/
```

The simplest option would be to move all the files and folders inside the `cakephp` directory up one level, as it's intended to work "out of the box", so the directory structure was like this:

```
# html/.htaccess               <- this file would then ...
# html/app
# html/app/.htaccess
# html/app/webroot             <- ... rewrite requests to here
# html/app/webroot/.htaccess
# html/cake
```

If you wish to keep the `cakephp` containing directory, then you will need to add your own `.htaccess` file to the `html/` directory to tell Apache of your intentions. The structure would be like this:

```
# html/.htaccess               <- your .htaccess file goes here
# html/cakephp/.htaccess       <- it should look similar to this one
# html/cakephp/app
# html/cakephp/app/.htaccess
# html/cakephp/app/webroot     <- you need to rewrite requests to here
# html/cakephp/app/webroot/.htaccess
# html/cakephp/cake
```

The contents of which can be copied from the first CakePHP .htaccess file (as noted above) and altered slightly to produce the result you are after. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$   cakephp/app/webroot/   [L] # rewrites requests to example.com/
RewriteRule (.*) cakephp/app/webroot/$1 [L] # rewrites requests to example.com/*
```

Comment: Hi Deizel, thanks for the reply dude. 
I used the 2nd approach you recommended and now the homepage's URL is showing up as desired.
But the controllers' pages are still showing the full URL, how should I edit the 3 .htaccess files in cakepho

Comment: I did some testing and see what you mean. My answer above only really considered the Apache side of things (.htaccess + mod_rewrite). I (incorrectly) assumed that CakePHP would have determined the correct base path (ie. `/` instead of `/cakephp/`). Unfortunately, the code that works this out is buried in the dispatcher, which would mean editing the core (see this hack: http://kushaura.com/blog/view/name:Installing-CakePHP-in-a-Subdirectory). I therefore suggest using one of the supported installation types (http://book.cakephp.org/view/32/Installation), such as the first one suggested.